# Why do I get TypeError: 0 is not a function when passing Array.from as a callback to Array.flatMap?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typeerror, flatmap

Passing Array.from as a callback to Array.flatMap causes an error: "TypeError: 0 is not a function"

```js
const x = ["12"].flatMap(Array.from)
console.log(x)
```

Despite this Array.from is usable as a function normally:

```js
const f = Array.from
console.log(f("12"))
```

I have found a way around this:

```js
const x = ["12"].flatMap(e => Array.from(e))
console.log(x)
```

I would like someone to tell me:

1. Why do I get an error?
2. Why do I get such an astonishingly unhelpful error message?

Comment: In Safari, the error message is more helpful: "TypeError: Array.from requires that the second argument, when provided, be a function"

Comment: Duplicate of [Why does parseInt yield NaN with Array#map?](/q/262427/4642212), because it’s the same cause.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate because someone googling for issues with Array.from and Array.flatMap is unlikely to look at a question about parseInt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#parameters) accepts up to 3 parameters, the second one being map function while [`.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#parameters) will pass to it iteration index as the second parameter.

So, on the first iteration, `Array.from` will recieve `0` as a second parameter, which, indeed, is not a function that `Array.from` expects.

To demonstrate it more clearly, here is a snippet. This line:

```js
["12"].flatMap(Array.from);
```

is functionally equivalent to:

```js
Array.from("12", 0, ["12"]);
```

which is an incorrect signature for `Array.from`.

Comment: Could you please add a snippet demonstrating that Array.flatMap passes 3 values to the callback? eg: flatMap((...args) => console.log(args))

Comment: Sure, here it is

Answer (score 3):

It happends because the flatMap passes more than 1 argument to the callback. The second argument is the index of the element. Array.from function expects a replacer function in the second argument. So this shortened version passed an index in place of a function.

What you're doing is equivalent to calling:

```js
Array.from("12", 0)
```

Instead of a proper replacer like:

```js
console.log(Array.from("12", x => x + x));
```